# Autodesk Maya fbx file export

Tags: export, maya, fbx

I used Maya LT 2016 version. After modeling I tried to Export my 2d character. I have already add plugins from windows menu.But still I have a error massage constraints error when exporting my 2d character. How solve it?

Comment: We cant help you solve something if we dont know what the problem is. Is it exporting? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your fbxmaya.dll is loaded without any error.
2. Make sure that you have selected " FBX Export" filter while exporting.
3. In the export dialog, there are many options make sure that you have selected the relevant options.
4. You can export your scene using MEL as well "FBXExport", MEL reference for more information.

If you have already followed all the steps, still if you get an error then please send us the error, I can help you.